# When considering two perpendicular forces how do u know where to measure the angle between resultant force?

Tags: magnetic-fields

For example in these two pictures below ?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the module of the resultant force is given by Pythagora's theorem as $|F| = \sqrt{|F_1|^2 + |F_2|^2}$. The size of the angle between the resultant force and one of the vectors comes from trigonometry. Explicitly, $\theta = \sin^{-1}(\frac{|F_y|}{|F|})$ or $\theta = \cos^{-1}(\frac{|F_x|}{|F|})$ as well as a formula with tan; i.e., $\theta = \tan(\frac{|F_y|}{|F_x|})$. This is the angle between the resultant force and one of the two vector though, as it is derived from trigonometry of a right angle triangle.

For example, in the picture you attached showing two vectors $R_x$ and $R_y$ the angle $\theta$ between $R_x$ and the resultant vector is given by $\theta = \cos^{-1}(\frac{R_x}{R})$ where $R$ is the sum of the two. Approximately this has value $\theta = 23^\circ$. On the other hand, the angle between $R_y$ and the resultant vector will be $\theta = \cos^{-1}(\frac{R_y}{R})$.

More generally, it is possible to find the angle between any two vectors by taking the dot product of them. However, from the images attached I believe this is what you meant.